# React Native, TouchableOpacity wrapping floating button get nothing

Tags: android, react-native, floating-action-button

I'm creating a simple action button (floating button)

This is working :

```
<View style={{
    width: this.props.size,
    height: this.props.size,
    borderRadius: this.props.size / 2,
    backgroundColor: '#ee6e73',
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 10,
    right: 10,
    flexDirection:'row'
}}>
    <Text>
        +
    </Text>
</View>
```

This is not :

```
<TouchableOpacity
        onPress={()=>{
        }} >
    <View style={{
        width: this.props.size,
        height: this.props.size,
        borderRadius: this.props.size / 2,
        backgroundColor: '#ee6e73',
        position: 'absolute',
        bottom: 10,
        right: 10,
        flexDirection:'row'
    }}>
        <Text>
            +
        </Text>
    </View>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Just wrap with TouchableOpacity then my button not show up without any errors.

React 0.1.7, Android

Then I try move styling from View to TouchableOpacity, It's work

```
<TouchableOpacity
        onPress={()=>{
        }} 
        style={{
            width: this.props.size,
            height: this.props.size,
            position: 'absolute',
            borderRadius: this.props.size / 2,
            backgroundColor: '#ee6e73',
            bottom: 10,
            right: 10,
        }}>
    <Text>
        +
    </Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Can any one explain me why?

React Native docs said

[https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchableopacity.html][1]

> A wrapper for making views respond properly to touches.
>   This is done without actually changing the view hierarchy, 
>   and in general is easy to add to an app without weird side-effects.

This mean I wrap my original view and it would work as I expected, But it's not.

Comment: Any way you can post the values of the this.props.size? Also, is there a specific reason you are using position: absolute? Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, I using position: absolute for floating a button in front of the others. this.props.size is for set the size of this button. It's a Number. e.g. <MyActionButton size={20} />

Answer (score 44, accepted):

From my experience, TouchableOpacity does not work well with `absolute` positioning. Perhaps if you remove that, the onPress will work again.

Also please note that it is EXTREMELY important what element you render first and what you render last.

For example, if you do:

```
<View>
    <TouchableOpacity style={{position:'absolute'}} onPress={()=> 
           {console.log("It works or not?")}}>
   </TouchableOpacity>
    <Text style={styles.aStyle}>
        Some text bla bla......
    </Text>
</View>
```

There is a pretty good chance that the Text will be rendered on top of the `TouchableOpacity`, therefore you won't be able to get the `onPress` working.

Then since the position is absolute, all you have to do is render it as the last child of the View:

```
<View>
    <Text style={styles.aStyle}>
        Some text bla bla
    </Text>
    <TouchableOpacity style={{position:'absolute'}} onPress={()=> 
       {console.log("It works or not?")}}>
   </TouchableOpacity>
</View>
```

Comment: I could have wasted days debugging, thank you for the component ordering part :)

Comment: Wow. Thank you very much. This solution of positioning it last worked for me  worked for me

Answer (score 6):

I know this is old but I had this issue and nothing above worked until adding `flex: 1` to my TouchableOpacity.

Answer (score 3):

TouchableOpacity does not assume the style of the view it is the parent of. You need provide it style information.

Comment: Just _what_ style information got this to work for you?

Answer (score 2):

Incase anyone else stumbles across this, and none of these suggestions work my fix was to instead import `TouchableOpacity` from `react-native` instead of `react-native-gesture-handler`

So

```
import { TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
```

Instead of

```
import { TouchableOpacity } from "react-native-gesture-handler";
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue after a lot of debugging I found out that negative margin was the problem.

**Beware of negative margin when using TouchableOpacity**

*Debugging step:*

1. Remove all the styling
2. Create fresh component without styling
3. Make sure it is working without styling
4. Then state adding your styling