# Why isn't `useContext` re-rendering my component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, gatsby, react-context

As per the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext):

> When the nearest `<MyContext.Provider>` above the component updates, this Hook will trigger a rerender with the latest context value passed to that MyContext provider. Even if an ancestor uses `React.memo` or `shouldComponentUpdate`, a rerender will still happen starting at the component itself using useContext.
>   ...
>   A component calling useContext will always re-render when the context value changes.

In my Gatsby JS project I define my Context as such:

**Context.js**

```
import React from "react"

const defaultContextValue = {
  data: {
    filterBy: 'year',
    isOptionClicked: false,
    filterValue: ''
  },
  set: () => {},
}

const Context = React.createContext(defaultContextValue)

class ContextProviderComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()

    this.setData = this.setData.bind(this)
    this.state = {
      ...defaultContextValue,
      set: this.setData,
    }
  }

  setData(newData) {
    this.setState(state => ({
      data: {
        ...state.data,
        ...newData,
      },
    }))
  }

  render() {
    return <Context.Provider value={this.state}>{this.props.children}</Context.Provider>
  }
}

export { Context as default, ContextProviderComponent }
```

In a layout.js file that wraps around several components I place the context provider:

**Layout.js**:

```
import React from 'react'
import { ContextProviderComponent } from '../../context'

const Layout = ({children}) => {

    return(
        <React.Fragment>
            <ContextProviderComponent>
                {children}
            </ContextProviderComponent>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
```

And in the component that I wish to consume the context in:

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react'
import Context from '../../../context'

const Visuals = () => {

    const filterByYear = 'year'
    const filterByTheme = 'theme'

    const value = useContext(Context)
    const { filterBy, isOptionClicked, filterValue } = value.data

    const data = <<returns some data from backend>>

    const works = filterBy === filterByYear ? 
        data.nodes.filter(node => node.year === filterValue) 
        : 
        data.nodes.filter(node => node.category === filterValue)

   return (
        <Layout noFooter="true">
            <Context.Consumer>
                {({ data, set }) => (
                    <div onClick={() => set( { filterBy: 'theme' })}>
                       { data.filterBy === filterByYear ? <h1>Year</h1> : <h1>Theme</h1> }
                    </div>
                )
            </Context.Consumer>
        </Layout>
    )
```

`Context.Consumer` works properly in that it successfully updates and reflects changes to the context. However as seen in the code, I would like to have access to updated context values in other parts of the component i.e outside the `return` function where `Context.Consumer` is used exclusively. I assumed using the `useContext` hook would help with this as my component would be re-rendered with new values from context every time the div is clicked - however this is not the case. Any help figuring out why this is would be appreciated.

TL;DR: `<Context.Consumer>` updates and reflects changes to the context from child component, `useContext` does not although the component needs it to.

**UPDATE:**
I have now figured out that `useContext` will read from the default context value passed to `createContext` and will essentially operate independently of `Context.Provider`. That is what is happening here, `Context.Provider` includes a method that modifies state whereas the default context value does not. My challenge now is figuring out a way to include a function in the default context value that can modify other properties of that value. As it stands:

```
const defaultContextValue = {
  data: {
    filterBy: 'year',
    isOptionClicked: false,
    filterValue: ''
  },
  set: () => {}
}
```

`set` is an empty function which is defined in the `ContextProviderComponent` (see above). How can I (if possible) define it directly in the context value so that:

```
const defaultContextValue = {
  data: {
    filterBy: 'year',
    isOptionClicked: false,
    filterValue: ''
  },
  test: 'hi',
  set: (newData) => {
     //directly modify defaultContextValue.data with newData
  }
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that default context value is only going to be used if there is no context provider in the consumer component ancestors.

Comment: @nicooga am I right in thinking that in this case default context value is passed as the value to the context provider and is therefore used regardless

Comment: Yes you are right, but it is redundant. You also don't need to wrap your elements in `Context.Consumer` if you are using `useContext`. Check this example: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-context-usage-example-04vkj.

Comment: ***"My challenge now is figuring out a way to include a function in the default context value that can modify other properties of that value*** - the usual pattern is to update Context with `useReducer()` [ref](https://medium.com/@seantheurgel/react-hooks-as-state-management-usecontext-useeffect-usereducer-a75472a862fe), although your set function approach might work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no need for you to use both `<Context.Consumer>` and the `useContext` hook.

By using the `useContext` hook you are getting access to the value stored in Context.

Regarding your specific example, a better way to consume the Context within your Visuals component would be as follows:

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import Context from "./context";

const Visuals = () => {
  const filterByYear = "year";
  const filterByTheme = "theme";

  const { data, set } = useContext(Context);
  const { filterBy, isOptionClicked, filterValue } = data;

  const works =
    filterBy === filterByYear
      ? "filter nodes by year"
      : "filter nodes by theme";

  return (
    <div noFooter="true">
      <div>
        {data.filterBy === filterByYear ? <h1>Year</h1> : <h1>Theme</h1>}
        the value for the 'works' variable is: {works}
        <button onClick={() => set({ filterBy: "theme" })}>
          Filter by theme
        </button>
        <button onClick={() => set({ filterBy: "year" })}>
          Filter by year
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Visuals;
```

Also, it seems that you are not using the `works` variable in your component which could be another reason for you not getting the desired results.

You can view a working example with the above implementation of `useContext` that is somewhat similar to your example in this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-ptolemy-l6qtu?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. I now understand that using both `Context.Consumer` and `useContext` is redundant. However the fundamental problem remains that the component is not re-rendered on context state change.

Comment: I believe that the issue might originate elsewhere in your code. if you could reproduce your error in a sandbox it would be easier to find the exact problem that is causing you trouble. If you take a look at the sandbox I shared you could see that the component rerenders every time the context changes.

Comment: Here's a sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-waterfall-e9s8b?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark. Currently working through yours as well

Comment: It seems that `isOptionsClicked` is always false so you are always rendering you `<Works/>` component and that `filterValue` is always an empty string so your `works` array is always empty.  This isn't an issue with context but with the implementation of the component's logic. I can't really give any more insight without seeing the full repo. Sorry.

Comment: That's alright. Really appreciate your help. I had this component working perfectly but I needed state to persist to other pages hence me rewriting it.

Comment: This is still not functioning as intended. Changing a value in the context does not trigger a re-render. If something else causes a render then you will see a new value (after the `set()` function is actually populated). If you use `useState()` it will cause a re-render .

https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-beaver-gvk2g

Comment: @Itai The sandbox link is broken. Mind fixing it.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was embarrassingly simple - `<Visuals>` was higher up in the component tree than `<Layout` was for some reason I'm still trying to work out. Marking Itai's answer as correct because it came closest to figuring things out giving the circumstances

Answer (score -1):

In addition to the solution cited by Itai, I believe my problem can help other people here

In my case I found something that had already happened to me, but that now presented itself with this other symptom, of not re-rendering the views that depend on a state stored in a context.

This is because there is a difference in dates between the host and the device. Explained here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/27008#issuecomment-592048282

And that has to do with the other symptom that I found earlier: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63800388/10947848

To solve this problem, just follow the steps in the first link, or if you find it necessary to just disable the debug mode