# Handle on press in a react-native custom component

Tags: react-native, custom-component

I'm using react-native. I need to show a menu that consists of a list of items. I simplified the code below and I'm showing only a text but in the real case, the item has got a checkbox an icon and a label so for this reason I created a custom component.
I need to handle the on click on the items.
The problem is that the on press on the `TouchableOpacity` in the widget is not triggered.
If I use the same hierarchy of components directly the on click works.

So in the example below the onClick on the `TouchableOpacity` that is directly put in the containing view is triggered but the onClick on the `TouchableOpacity` that is wrapped in the `EventOnMapMenuWidget` is not triggered.

How can I handle the onClick on the `TouchableOpacity` in the `EventOnMapMenuWidget`?

Please notice that in the log I don't see the

> EventOnMapMenuWidget onPress

while I see the

> TEST onPress

```
private drawEventsOnMapForm() {
    return <View style={{ margin: marginStyle.medium, flexDirection: 'column' }}>
            <EventOnMapMenuWidget
                onToggle={() => {
                    console.log("EventOnMapMenuWidget onToggle")
                }}
                label={STRINGS.speeding}
            />
            <TouchableOpacity style={{ margin: marginStyle.medium, flexDirection: 'row' }} onPress={() => {
                console.log("TEST onPress")
            }}>
                <Text style={{ color: COLORS.black }}>{STRINGS.speeding}</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
}
```

This is the definition of the custom components:

```
export default class EventOnMapMenuWidget extends Component<EventOnMapMenuWidgetProp> {
    render() {
        return <TouchableOpacity style={{ margin: marginStyle.medium, flexDirection: 'row' }} onPress={()=> {
            console.log("EventOnMapMenuWidget onPress", this.props.label)
            this.props.onToggle()
        }}>
            <Text style={{color: COLORS.black}}>{this.props.label}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to work as expected. https://snack.expo.io/@nipuna777/fascinated-milkshake You could try adding backgroundColors to TouchableOpacity to make sure that they are positioned where they should be.

Comment: Thank you @nipuna777. For some reasons in the app, it does not work. I have even tried to create another snipped like yours where I copied almost everything I have in the app. It is still working but it doesn't in the app. I managed to make it work using a View instead of the TouchableOpacity and wrapping the View with a Button. It is not ideal but it works.

Comment: this was the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56090392/987753